# How to copy and paste values (non-adjacent columns, preserving values in target range)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to paste from source range to target range but skipping one column in target and keeping the values already there (the ones other than those in source range). One code I was using before was able to keep the existing values and just append the ones not matched from source to last row. But with an improvement to skip columns, the values are pasted over the ones I actually wanna keep (not to the last row with no values).

First code snippet:

```
function appendSheet1ToSheet2() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1:C');
      const target = ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1:D');
      appendUniquesToRange_(source, target);
}
    
function appendUniquesToRange_(sourceRange, targetRange) {
      const dataToAppend = sourceRange.getValues().map(row => [row[0], row[1], ,row[2]]);
      const existingData = targetRange.getValues()
      const newData = existingData
        .concat(dataToAppend) 
        .filter((row, rowIndex, array) =>
          array
            .map(tuple => tuple[0])
            .indexOf(row[0]) === rowIndex && row[0] !== ''
        );
      targetRange
        .offset(0, 0, newData.length, newData[0].length)
        .setValues(newData);
}
```

Improvement to `appendSheet1ToSheet2` which skips column, but doesn't seem to keep values in range that I want kept, just pastes over.

```
function appendSheet1ToSheet2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRangeList(["A1:B", "C1:C"]).getRanges();
  const target = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRangeList(["A2", "D2"]).getRanges();
  source.forEach((r, i) => r.copyTo(target[i]));
}
```

Here is the [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cAoG3ms4e384nWCZe2wBNQUkExnIQ1zZertYXlwQT0I/edit#gid=1608566496). What I want is values/count/link 2&3 to be appended to sheet2 in row 6 and 7 (column A,B,D). How can I basically combine the two codes to make this improvement? Hope that's clear.

Thanks

Comment: You may have to get the values in the target sheet and incorporate them into the final data set or you may be forced to use atleast two separate data sets to do the final setValues().

Answer (score 2):

So, do you want to keep all the values in column C of the target sheet intact?

It can be done pretty easy with the three additional lines in the function `appendSheet1ToSheet2()`:

```
function appendSheet1ToSheet2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1:C');
  const target = ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1:D');
  const col_c = ss.getRange('Sheet2!C1:C');  // <--- get the column
  const col_c_values = col_c.getValues();    // <--- get the old values
  appendUniquesToRange_(source, target);
  col_c.setValues(col_c_values);             // <--- put the old values back
}
```

But I'm not sure if it makes sense. Because it's hard to tell what the columns A, B and D will contain after append the new data from the source sheet.